# Magento : How to get category page title attribute (meta title) as html page title

Tags: php, magento

in my requirements i need to set the category page title attribute as me category page title but for some my misfortune it is not setting as expected i have checked the magento wiki's they are it should...

I have tried by getting the current category ID and then load it on the header file to get the meta_title attribute

```
$current_id=  Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$catobj = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($current_id);
print_r($catobj);
echo $catobj->getMetaTitle();
```

But the $catobj->getMetaTitle() is giving the category name rather than the category page title :-(

I have also tried printing the category obj and saw category meta_title is there

**Mage_Catalog_Model_Category Object ( [_eventPrefix:protected] => catalog_category [_eventObject:protected] => category [_cacheTag:protected] => catalog_category [_useFlatResource:protected] => [_designAttributes:Mage_Catalog_Model_Category:private] => Array ( [0] => custom_design [1] => custom_design_from [2] => custom_design_to [3] => page_layout [4] => custom_layout_update [5] => custom_apply_to_products ) [_treeModel:protected] => [_defaultValues:protected] => Array ( [meta_title] => HP Inkjet Printer Cartridges | Trendsetter [name] => HP Inkjets [url_key] => hp-inkjets [url_path] => printer-consumables/hp/hp-inkjets [is_active] => 1 [available_sort_by] => ) [_storeValuesFlags:protected] => Array ( [meta_title] => 1 [name] => 1 [url_key] => 1 [url_path] => 1 [is_active] => 1 [available_sort_by] => 1 ) [_lockedAttributes:protected] => Array ( ) [_isDeleteable:protected] => 1 [_isReadonly:protected] => [_resourceName:protected] => catalog/category [_resource:protected] => [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => catalog/category_collection [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1 [_isObjectNew:protected] => [_data:protected] => Array ( [entity_id] => 261 [entity_type_id] => 3 [attribute_set_id] => 3 [parent_id] => 259 [created_at] => 2012-12-11 13:00:28 [updated_at] => 2013-02-26 12:08:33 [path] => 1/13/520/259/261 [position] => 248 [level] => 2 [children_count] => 0 [name] => HP Inkjets [display_mode] => PRODUCTS [meta_title] => HP Inkjets [url_key] => hp-inkjets [url_path] => printer-consumables/hp/hp-inkjets [custom_design] => [page_layout] => [is_active] => 1 [is_anchor] => 0 [include_in_menu] => 1 [landing_page] => [custom_use_parent_settings] => 0 [custom_apply_to_products] => 0 [available_sort_by] => [description] => [meta_keywords] => HP inkjet printer cartridges [meta_description] => High quality HP printer ink and cartridges at extremely low prices. [custom_layout_update] => [custom_design_from] => [custom_design_to] => [filter_price_range] => ) [_hasDataChanges:protected] => [_origData:protected] => Array ( [entity_id] => 261 [entity_type_id] => 3 [attribute_set_id] => 3 [parent_id] => 259 [created_at] => 2012-12-11 13:00:28 [updated_at] => 2013-02-26 12:08:33 [path] => 1/13/520/259/261 [position] => 248 [level] => 2 [children_count] => 0 [name] => HP Inkjets [display_mode] => PRODUCTS [meta_title] => HP Inkjets [url_key] => hp-inkjets [url_path] => printer-consumables/hp/hp-inkjets [custom_design] => [page_layout] => [is_active] => 1 [is_anchor] => 0 [include_in_menu] => 1 [landing_page] => [custom_use_parent_settings] => 0 [custom_apply_to_products] => 0 [available_sort_by] => [description] => [meta_keywords] => HP inkjet printer cartridges [meta_description] => High quality HP printer ink and cartridges at extremely low prices. [custom_layout_update] => [custom_design_from] => [custom_design_to] => [filter_price_range] => ) [_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id [_isDeleted:protected] => [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array ( ) )**

and tried

```
echo $catobj->meta_title;
```

But this also giving the same **category name** :-(
please help with this.

I have debug the category obj

```
print_r($catobj->debug());
```

but this showing that meta_title is same as name but its not, its different.. really annoying

**Array ( [entity_id] => 261 [entity_type_id] => 3 [attribute_set_id] => 3 [parent_id] => 259 [created_at] => 2012-12-11 13:00:28 [updated_at] => 2013-02-26 12:08:33 [path] => 1/13/520/259/261 [position] => 248 [level] => 2 [children_count] => 0 [name] => HP Inkjets [display_mode] => PRODUCTS [meta_title] => HP Inkjets [url_key] => hp-inkjets [url_path] => printer-consumables/hp/hp-inkjets [is_active] => 1 [is_anchor] => 0 [include_in_menu] => 1 [custom_use_parent_settings] => 0 [custom_apply_to_products] => 0 [meta_keywords] => HP inkjet printer cartridges [meta_description] => High quality HP printer ink and cartridges at extremely low prices. ) HP Inkjets**

Comment: Have you tried this?

$head = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
    $head->setTitle("Your Category Title"); 
}

Comment: @chapagain many thanks for suggesting, but this is something like i am hard-coding the titles i need to get the attr(meta_title) value from the category object so that i can set in the setTitle method...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well after searching through the internet i found solution to my problem that, the store group was wrong. 
Thanks

Comment: This should be the comment just below your question instead of answer.

Answer (score 0):

$catgId = Category ID

```
$catSel = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catgId); 
            $catDesc = array(
            'id' => $catgId,
            'desc' => $catSel->getDescription(),
            'url-key' => $catSel->getUrl_key(),
            'title' => $catSel->getMetaTitle()
        );
```